# Expiring links and where to store them

Tags: php, mysql, xcache

I currently have a website setup where unique links are generated every time a person loads a page. When a user follows a link that link should expire. That is, they shouldn't be able to hit back on their browser and click that link again.

While I can do this now, I'm not sure where I should be storing the unique link IDs.

There are going to be a lot of links generated since the website involves a lot of clicking through to get to other sections of the site, but the links themselves will expire after 30 minutes.

Should I store them on the database (MySQL) or cache them in memory with xcache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to ever reference the links again (ie an audit trail) storing them in memory should be fine, even storing them in [session()](http://www.php.net/session) should be acceptable. If you want an audit trail, I would store them in a more permanent matter, IE a database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't think about trying to use session(). I guess as long as I don't fill up the memory cache I won't need to use sessions yet.